# UWP project unit test: Inconclusive: A user callback threw an exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, uwp, tdd, mstest

I have a UWP project which fails to run unit tests via R#.

I know this was very cumbersome in the beginning of UWP, but I was able to get the unit tests going if I restarted Visual Studio a couple of times. A year later, and a major release further in VS2017 and R# I am still not able to run unit tests...

I'm using:

- VS2017 Pro (15.4.3)
- R# 2017.2.2 ultimate
- UWP solution with target project Creators update (15063)
- MS test project (15063)

When I open my solution, it doesn't matter which unit test I run, every test will be inconclusive.

[image]

Does anybody recognize these kind of issues and have a workaround for this? Any way to at least allow some kind of TDD way of working?

PS: Of course there isn't an actual stack-trace or inner exception in an output window which I can use for troubleshooting. It's just this pointless message without any useful suggestion how to move further